# Mongodb - Update the value of object's array's key value

Tags: mongodb

I have below documents in the collection.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c98760c27b9fb1266f996b3"), 
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5c8109785b9a5427b167542a"), 
    "permissions" : [
        {
            "dashboard" : [
                "Pie Chart", 
                "Bar Chart"
            ], 
            "product management" : [
                "update", 
                "delete", 
                "list", 
                "insert"
            ], 
            "app user listing" : [
                "insert", 
                "update", 
                "delete", 
                "list"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to perform below query:

```
db.user_permissions.update(

    { user_id: ObjectId("5c8740860c5dcf6c615c1ba3") },
    { 
        "permissions.app user listing": ['inserts']
    }

)
```

what I want to do is to update the value of "app user listing".

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: 
This is what I want

Expected Outpupt:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c98760c27b9fb1266f996b3"), 
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5c8109785b9a5427b167542a"), 
    "permissions" : [
        {
            "dashboard" : [
                "Pie Chart", 
                "Bar Chart"
            ], 
            "product management" : [
                "update", 
                "delete", 
                "list", 
                "insert"
            ], 
            "app user listing" : [
                "inserts"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to update value of given key with array.

Comment: why don't you change the attribute's name with snake case? i.e:`app_user_listing`?

Comment: Remove `ObjectId` from the update matching also: `{user_id : "5c8740860c5dcf6c615c1ba3"}` would be enough

Comment: @vahdet it isn't/won't work

Comment: @Kai I wish I could

Comment: All in all, what problem do you have with your current code? Does it update nothing? Throws an exception, etc?

Comment: @vahdet check my edit

Comment: Paste your error if any?

Comment: Will this work only on [0] elements of permission array?

Comment: What version of mongo you are using?

Answer (score 1):

This works on all versions on mongo, you need second argument for find,

```
    db.myColl.update( 
    {
        "user_id" : ObjectId("5c8109785b9a5427b167542a"),"permissions.app user listing":["insersssts"] 
    },
    {
        $set: {
        "permissions.$.app user listing":["insertss"]      
    }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try as below:

```
db.user_permission.update(
    {
        "user_id" : ObjectId("5c8109785b9a5427b167542a")
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "permissions.$[].app user listing": ['inserts']
        }
    },
    {
        upsert:false
    }
)
```

Data before running query :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c98760c27b9fb1266f996b3"),
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5c8109785b9a5427b167542a"),
    "permissions" : [
        {
            "dashboard" : [
                "Pie Chart",
                "Bar Chart"
            ],
            "product management" : [
                "update",
                "delete",
                "list",
                "insert"
            ],
            "app user listing" : [
                "insert",
                "update",
                "delete",
                "list"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

After running query:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c98760c27b9fb1266f996b3"),
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5c8109785b9a5427b167542a"),
    "permissions" : [
        {
            "dashboard" : [
                "Pie Chart",
                "Bar Chart"
            ],
            "product management" : [
                "update",
                "delete",
                "list",
                "insert"
            ],
            "app user listing" : [
                "inserts"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this?
This is the error `cannot use the part (permissions of permissions.$[].app_user_listing) to traverse the element ({permissions: [ { dashboard: [ "Pie Chart", "Bar Chart" ], product management: [ "update", "delete", "list", "insert" ], app user listing: [ "inserts" ] } ]})
`

Comment: This error might be due to underscores. I updated my post to try once again.

And i tested it at my end, it works fine.

Comment: I tried without using underscores (same as in your case). and it also works.

Comment: will it be used in waterline orm ?

Comment: I am running this query in mongodb GUI "NoSqlBooster".

Comment: Try running on Robomongo or mongo shell, it fails

Comment: Running fine with "Robomongo" as well.

Comment: My MongoDB shell version is v3.6.8.

Comment: I guess this does not work with mongo 3.4.x. On my end it is failing